# Run an application in foreground using gitlab runner

Tags: python, windows, shell, gitlab-ci

I am trying to open an application from gitlab runner using command prompt but that application opens in background. I need to open it in foreground.

I am opening the command terminal using subprocess.Popen() but it launches application in background

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code. What program are you running and why do you think you need it in the foreground -- what are you trying to achieve? I'm not sure why you would start a terminal using `subprocess.Popen` -- The terminal is used to run commands... why not just invoke the commands directly using `subprocess.Popen` ?